# $\mathbb{N}$ isn't a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that $\mathbb{N}$ isn't a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. I want to say this is true, since for instance $1/2 \cdot 1 = 1/2$ which is not in $\mathbb{N}$.  I know this isn't that simple.  I'm missing something.  Please help.

Comment: Why is it not that simple?

Comment: This is *absolutely* true.

Comment: What is the problem with your counterexample? It looks just fine to me...

Comment: I'm skeptical that it's that easy since this was a bonus problem.

Comment: Your skepticism might be justified: the exercise might not be assuming that the putative vector space structure on $\Bbb N$ is given by the *usual* multiplication. It could just be asking of there exists an operation $\Bbb R\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ obeying such and such properties making $\Bbb N$ a vector space over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Looking at the question, one must show that there is *no* structure of $\mathbb R$-vector space on $\mathbb N$. Not that $(r,n) \mapsto rn$ does not define a $\mathbb R$-vector space structure on $\mathbb N$. So the doubt of the OP is very legit.

Comment: If you can't rely on ${\mathbb N}$ being equipped with its usual operations, then you also can't rely on ${\mathbb R}$ being equipped with its usual operations. Still, whatever you do with the operations, ${\mathbb N}$ won't ever be a vectorspace over ${\mathbb R}$ because of cardinality reasons.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{N}$ is countable, but a non-zero vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable , because  $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine, but here is an even stronger result.

**Proposition** There exists no countable nonzero $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

*Proof.*
Seeking a contradiction, suppose that $V$ is a countable nonzero $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. Then there exists a nonzero $v\in V$ and $\mathrm{Span}\{v\}$ is countable. That is, there exist distinct $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda_1 \cdot v=\lambda_2\cdot v$. This implies $(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)\cdot v=\mathbf{0}$ and multiplying by $(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^{-1}$ gives $v=\mathbf{0}$, a contradiction.  $\Box$

Comment: I think the stronger result is what the OP needs.  He/she assumes that scalar multiplication is just multiplication of two numbers, which it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 0):

The clearest problem is that $(\mathbb N, +)$ isn't a group. It lacks inverses, such as $-1$. For this reason, $\mathbb N$ isn't a vector space over $\mathbb R$, or a vector space over any other field, or even a module over any ring.

I guess $\mathbb N$ is a semimodule over the semiring $\mathbb N$. That's probably the most direct analogy to a vector space that it affords.

Comment: Who said the additive structure on $\mathbb N$ was the usual addition ? Take any countable abelian group and transfer the structure on $\mathbb N$, it gives a perfectly good abelian group structure on $\mathbb N$ which could serve as the underlying group of a vector space.

Comment: @Pece The question is ambiguous, so I made the choice to address $(\mathbb N, +)$ specifically. I don't claim to have answered all possible interpretations of the question!